# get Hebrew parameters from query string asp.net explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, httprequest

when I try to get parameter in Hebrew from the query string in the System.Web.HttpRequest . I get Question marks instead of the word.

```
string hebName = Request[FirstName].ToString();
hebName = ������
```

In chrome it works fine, but in Explorer I get this error.

Comment: document.charset? use utf-8 encoding.... add <meta charset="utf-8"/> as your first entry in the <head> section of your web page.